# Extending definition for express Request, in typescript results in "does not exist on type"?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to add a new field 'ws' on the Express Request definition, as declared in `@types/express`, but at runtime I am running into the error:

> `src/routes/api/messages.ts:11:20 - error TS2339: Property 'ws' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any>'`

I have created a `custom.d.ts` file, in my project:

```
export {};

declare global {
    namespace Express {
        interface Request {
            ws?: any;
        }
    }
}
```

This file is placed in `src/types/` and the folder is in turn reference by `tsconfig.json`, in both the `compilerOptions -> typeRoots` and `paths` sections (key sections only in example):

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "node_modules/@types",
        "src/types/*"
    },
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "node_modules/*",
        "src/types/*"
      ]
    },
}
```

This all seems to satisfy the VS Code Typescript environment, but fails at runtime. Dev runtime is using `nodemon server`, with `nodemon.json` contents:

```
  {
    "watch": ["src"],
    "ext": "ts",
    "ignore": ["src/**/*.spec.ts"],
    "exec": "ts-node ./src/index.ts"
  }
```

At the moment my only workaround is to access the field as follows:

```
const ws = (req as any).ws
```

I am using express 4 and typescript 3.8.3.

Answer (score 0):

Found a working solution, based on a [ts-node bug report](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/782):

Essentially ts-node needs to be called with the `--files` option. So from the CLI:

```sh
ts-node --files src
```

or `nodemon.json`:

```
{
    "watch": ["src"],
    "ext": "ts",
    "ignore": ["src/**/*.spec.ts"],
    "exec": "ts-node --files ./src/index.ts"
}
```